# Open command prompt from final builder

Tags: build, cmd, production-environment

Is it possible to open a **command prompt** from inside final builder 6.. with the env created from inside final builder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the Execute Program Action, set the Program File to %DOSCMD% and turn off Wait for Completion and Hide Window. Any environment variables you set in FinalBuilder will be available in the command prompt window.